# I have a background image in a div on my HTML page, and I would like it to change to a different image and back to the first one every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

i have a sections structure webpage and i have this image that i want to change to another one every x seconds, how do i do it?

This is the HTML code:

```
<section id="sec1" class="sec1">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="herotxt">
      <h1>¡Bienvenidos!</h1>
      <p> Deseamos que seas parte <br>
        de nuestra comunidad educativa <br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And This is my css where the background img comes from:

```
.content .sec1:nth-child(1) {
    background-image: url(sources/11-5.JPG);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In my local folder  sources/img i have two images which are 11-5.jpg] and 11-4.jpg.

How do i change the 11-5.jpg to 11-4.jpg and then repeat that every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Javascript setInterval with 3000 ms interval time, try this :

```js
let sectionElm = document.querySelector('.sec1:nth-child(1)');
let arrayImg = ['https://dummyimage.com/600x400/b300b3/fff','https://dummyimage.com/600x400/035cf5/fff']
let indexChosen = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  sectionElm.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+arrayImg[indexChosen]+"')";
  if(indexChosen) {
    indexChosen = 0;
  } else {
    indexChosen = 1;
  }
}, 3000);
```

```css
.sec1:nth-child(1) {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="sec1" class="sec1">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="herotxt">
            <h1>¡Bienvenidos!</h1>
            <p> Deseamos que seas parte <br>
                de nuestra comunidad educativa <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Omg ty! it actually worked! is it posible to make the change smoother? like with an animation or something like that?

Comment: Just add `transition: all 0.5s ease-in;` in CSS section